# Link to a specific tab in another page with an anchor tag by using Django and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, anchor

I have an href link in one page, when clicking I need to open a specific tab in another page.
In the second page I have multiple tabs. In more detail:

**Page 1**
I'm using Django template tag with anchor to go to the page with the tabs. url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/payments#payments`

```html
<div class="shop-info">
   <a href="{% url 'payments' %}#payments">
    <div class="footer-links">Payments</div>
   </a>
    <div class="footer-links">Shipping</div>
    <div class="footer-links">Returns</div>  
</div>
```

**Page 2**

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  // get the tab from url
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  // if a hash is present (when you come to this page)
  if (hash !='') {
    // show the tab
    $('.tabs a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
  }
});
```

```html
<div data-duration-in="300" data-duration-out="100" class="tabs w-tabs">
     <div class="tabs-menu w-tab-menu">
      <a data-w-tab="Tab 1" class="tab-links w-inline-block w-tab-link">
        <div>Payments</div>
      </a>
      <a data-w-tab="Tab 2" class="tab-links w-inline-block w-tab-link">
        <div>Shipping</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="tabs-content w-tab-content">
     <div data-w-tab="Tab 1" class="payments-text w-tab-pane">
      <div class="w-richtext">
        {{ settings.payments|safe }}
      </div>
     </div>
     <div data-w-tab="Tab 2" class="shipping-text w-tab-pane">
      <div class="w-richtext">
        {{ settings.shipping|safe }}
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I understand that in order for this to work i need to use some javascript however i'm not quite familiar. After reading a couple of similar issues I added following code in the page 2 but with no success:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  // get the tab from url
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  // if a hash is present (when you come to this page)
  if (hash !='') {
    // show the tab
    $('.tabs a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
  }
});
</script>
```

I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tab is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (payments:525)
    at e (jquery-3.5.1.min.dc5e7f18c8.js?site=60411dcb7a606f33e31c3ee2:2)
    at t (jquery-3.5.1.min.dc5e7f18c8.js?site=60411dcb7a606f33e31c3ee2:2)
```

Thank you

Comment: Hi, which plugin are you using for tab ?

Comment: Hello Swati!! :) Template is developed with webflow. This is script used for tab.

  <script src="https://d3e54v103j8qbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.dc5e7f18c8.js?site=60411dcb7a606f33e31c3ee2" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/webflow.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".w-webflow-badge").removeClass("w-webflow-badge").empty();
    });
</script>

I hope this is what you are asking for.

Comment: tab is jquery plugin ? can you link to page where this tab plugin documentation is there . I think you have not included all libraries .

Comment: Hi Swati! Sorry for the late response. As you stated a library was missing. After adding it problem solved. Thank you once moere.